# How to include a html page from server which will be displayed at the php email body?

Tags: php, html, email

I want to send an email and instead of 'some text', I want it to echo the page.html from server and that page to be all the email.

```
$mail->Body    = 'some text';
```

Thank you!

Comment: `$mail->Body  = file_get_contents('page.html')`. I'm pretty sure this is not what you want, but this is the exact answer to your question :o) Please expand and explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

use `file_get_contents` to achieve this

```
<?php 

// this will get content of file as a string 
$htmlContent = file_get_contents("path/to/page.html");

$mail->Body = $htmlContent;
?>
```

> Reference - **[File get Content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**